# Magento url rewrites to local ip

Tags: magento

I've installed Magento CE in my xampp enviroment. Everything works fine except that I'm having problem with vhost and access to the site over the internet. When I type the domain name it resolves from e.g. mydomain.com to 127.0.0.1/magento in my url field. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the base url you entered at installation? you can see it in the table `core_config_data`. It has the `path` `web/unsecure/base_url`

Comment: The base url is "http://"localhost/eCommerce (without the ""). Should I change this to www.mydomain.com?

Comment: yes, you shold change that. Actually change anything that looks like that link in the `core_config_data` table.

Comment: Okay I've changed both web/unsecure/base_url and secure to www.mydomain.com and restarted apache. When I type the domain it changes the url to 127.0.0.1/eCommerce. It works on my local server when I do www.mydomain.com but thats becuase the rootfolder is located there.

Comment: Clear the contents of 'var/cache' folder

Comment: ok it worked but try www.lowkey.se Not sure what I've done wrong here. I just cleared the magento cache.

Comment: You forgot a slash at the end of the url. It should be `http://www.lowkey.se/`

Comment: Ah thank you! :DD can't upvote not enough points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you didn't update your database with your current domain name. In magento we have a core_config_data table , so there you need to update your current url

Comment: Ok thank you. I'm sitting in class atm but I'll update it later on.